# How to center block elements while wrapping and enable horizontal scroll with min width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to finish my photography portfolio website and got stuck. Sorry if i'm not able to be specific as i'm a newbie in coding.
I would like to have the image thumbnails always in center. When the horizontal browser window size gets smaller the 4 column is wrapping to a 3 column which is fine but then the thumbnails are not in center, they are more on the left.
The other thing is the innertube2. I have a fixed width of 1220px in 2 rows without wrapping. I would like to to force horizontal scroll bar if the browser window size gets smaller than that. Else the innertube2 is disappearing from the right side. I tried overflow:auto, but i don't like the scroll bar right underneath the innertube2, i would prefer on the bottom of the browser.
A min width of 1220px would be also fine for the thumbnails with a min column count of 3.
Thank you VERY much in advance!!!`

```html
<style type="text/css">
  a.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    height: 187px;
    margin: 40px 20px 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: Black;
  }
  a.thumbnail:hover {
    color: #d89a5f;
  }
  a.thumbnail img {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  a.thumbnail:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  a.thumbnail span {
    font-family: 'CustomFont';
    display: block;
    font-size: h1;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2px;
    color: #d5d5d5;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  a.thumbnail:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  img {
    border: 0px solid #CCC;
  }
  pre {
    display: block;
    font: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 0px solid #bae2f0;
    background: #ef1d45;
    margin: .5em 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 800px;
  }
  #container {
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 150px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  body {
    text align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #161614;
  }
  #bgdiv {
    position: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    Height of frame div
  }
  #framecontent {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #282828 url(img/logo.jpg) left no-repeat;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #282828;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-style: solid none none none;
  }
  #maincontent {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .innertube2 {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 1220px;
    margin: auto auto;
  }
  .innertube {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 800px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  * html body {
    padding: 0 0 130px 0;
  }
  * html #maincontent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #underlinemenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #underlinemenu2 ul {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid #DFDFDF;
    border-width: 0px 0;
  }
  #underlinemenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left: 0;
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid #DFDFDF;
    border-width: 0px 0;
  }
  * html #underlinemenu ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  * html #underlinemenu2 ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  #underlinemenu2 ul li {
    display: inline;
  }
  #underlinemenu ul li {
    display: inline;
  }
  #underlinemenu ul li a {
    float: left;
    color: #d5d5d5;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 2px 20px 4px 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #282828;
  }
  #underlinemenu2 ul li a {
    float: left;
    color: #ea9b3c;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #282828
  }
  .list {
    background: (logo.jpg) right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  .center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    color: #161614;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>

  <div>

    <div id="container">
      <div class="yoxview">

        <a class="thumbnail" href="01_big.jpg">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/280x187" title="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" alt="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" /><span>ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="01_big.jpg">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/280x187" title="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" alt="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" /><span>ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="01_big.jpg">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/280x187" title="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" alt="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" /><span>ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="01_big.jpg">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/280x187" title="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" alt="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" /><span>ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="01_big.jpg">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/280x187" title="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" alt="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" /><span>ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="01_big.jpg">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/280x187" title="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" alt="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" /><span>ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="01_big.jpg">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/280x187" title="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" alt="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" /><span>ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="01_big.jpg">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/280x187" title="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" alt="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" /><span>ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="01_big.jpg">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/280x187" title="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" alt="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" /><span>ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="01_big.jpg">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/280x187" title="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" alt="ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" /><span>ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </a>








      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="footer">
      <div class="innertube2">
        <div id="underlinemenu2">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="t.html" title="test">test</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="framecontent">
          <div class="innertube">
            <div id="underlinemenu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="t.html" title="test">aaaaaaaaaa</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="t.html" title="test">bbbbbbbbbb</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="t.html" title="test">cccccccccc</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="t.html" title="test">dddddddddd</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="t.html" title="test">eeeeeeeeee</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="t.html" title="test">ffffffffff</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to insert this code on the style of the image:

```
position: relative; 
left: 50%; 
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

That will make the image stay in the middle of your `<body>`, always.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, i.e., images in center correct your css as follows:

```
a.thumbnail {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   width: 280px;
   height: 187px;
   margin: 40px 20px 20px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: Black;
   text-align:center;
  }
```

and for your second problem, i.e., scrollbar at bottom correct your css as follows:

```
.innertube2 {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 1220px;
    margin: auto auto;
    float: left;
    overflow: scroll;
    }
#underlinemenu2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    }
#framecontent {
    /* position: fixed; */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #282828 url(img/logo.jpg) left no-repeat;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried but the thumbnails are still not centered,they stay more on the left side. The second solution is also not working. I got a vertical scroll bar but no horizontal when the browser size is smaller then 1220px. Thanks!